How do I execute streamlit code in PyCharm that imports local python package?
I have a python project set up in PyCharm with a python package called "demo" in the root directory. I've successfully imported it in other scripts as "from demo.example import ...".
I have a directory "gui" and in that is a code that uses streamlit. In order to successfully use absolute imports, I've had to click on the "Run" button and not use CLI. However, to run the streamlit app, I've had to use "streamlit run main.py".
When I click on "Run", I get the following error:
AttributeError: st.session_state has no attribute "messages". Did you forget to initialize it?

And when I execute "streamlit run main.py", I get this:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demo'

How do I solve this?

project_root/
│
├── demo/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── example.py
│   └── ...
│
├── gui/
│   ├── main.py
│   └── ...
│
└── ...

If your project directory its like this, I think that you config the python path in PyCharm
File -> Settings -> Project: <name> -> Python Interpreter

Also, review a relative import
from ..demo.example import function

Hope can help you
